# Using asyc/await/task over multiple method calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've been trying to understand async/await to make sure the UI doesn't block when loading something from the database. This is what I have so far, but it's not working at all:

VM:

```
public LoadingViewModel(IRoleService roleService)
{
    RoleService = roleService;
    StartLoading();
}

private IEnumerable<Role> StartLoading()
{
    Roles = RoleService.GetAllRoles();
}
```

RoleService:

```
public IEnumerable<Role> GetAllRoles()
{
    return Repository.GetAll<Role>().Result;
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAll<T>() where T : class
{
    return await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<T>());
}
```

I thought this could work, but apparently it doesn't as the UI still hangs. I did get it to work by creating another Task in the RoleService, but I don't think you're supposed to make more and more tasks...

I've been trying for a while and I've read a lot about it, but I just don't get it.

Could someone explain why this doesn't work and how I can actually get it to work?

EDIT:
After looking at the answer, I now have this, but it still doesn't work. I'll look at the constructor problem later.

VM:

```
public LoadingViewModel(IRoleService roleService)
{
    RoleService = roleService;

    //change this later
    var roles = StartLoading();
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<Role>> StartLoading()
{
    var roles = await RoleService.GetAllRolesAsync();

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(role.Name);
    }
    return roles;
}
```

RoleService:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Role>> GetAllRolesAsync()
{
    return await Repository.GetAll<Role>();
}
```

Repository:

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<T>());
    }
```

The UI still hangs - what am I doing wrong now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `Result` on the task, which synchronously waits for the task to finish.  Since you're calling this from the UI thread, it will block the UI thread for the duration of that `Task`'s execution.  Since that task needs to post a callback to the UI thread, and you're blocking the UI thread and preventing any UI messages from being processed, that `Task` will of course never complete, resulting in the UI hanging forever.

You need to not synchronously wait on the asynchronous operations; you need the entire call stack to be asynchronous.  (You need to "async all the way up".)

Comment: +1. For the special case of "async constructors", I have [a few approaches on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) - also see [async properties for async data-binding](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html). Note that you must *synchronously* construct your ViewModels to a "loading" state and then asynchronously *update* them to a "loaded" state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you have a look at it again? I still don't get it to work, even though I'm now asyncing the whole call stack...

Comment: @Bv202 You need to remember that an `IQueryable` is the representation of a query, not the results of that query.  Creating an `IQueryable` takes virtually no time as it merely creates an object that can be used, when iterated, to execute a database query.  It is only when you iterate it that the database is actually queried.  You're asynchronously constructing the query, and synchronously executing it.

Comment: Okay, thank for the info, I understand what you mean. But how to solve this? In order to actually execute the query (by using ToList() or something else) I have to get the Result property, but I can't access it here or my async code stops?

Comment: @Bv202 What you *should* do is use EF's methods to execute the query asynchronously, i.e. `ToListAsync`, and avoid synchronously waiting on asynchronous IO from a thread pool thread.

Comment: This is my code:             var members =  await Repository.GetAll<Member>();
            return await members.ToListAsync();

Comment: @Bv202 Then somewhere in your code your synchronously waiting on something, if not here, then elsewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70418/discussion-between-bv202-and-servy).